# permalink about in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am wondering, whenever I try to change the permalink in "Add New Page" to `about` it always change to `about-2`. I check the pages, I don't have any About page yet that exists. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a support request for a third-party software, here namely Wordpress. It is much better suited on a venue focussing on Wordpress support like the Wordpress Support Forums or - if in the scope of that site - on Wordpress Stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

It could be possible that you have a duplicate page in the Trash, or a duplicate permalink on a page with a different title.